# "hyphenation" in Biblical Hebrew

Tags: xetex

I am typesetting Biblical Hebrew using \raggedleft because in general one can not hyphenate. Even with  \Xetex I ran into a problem because  of a  "maqeif".

What are the rules? I.e. in typesetting Biblical Hebrew is  one allowed to split a "maqeif" combination e.g . 'eht-qolee after the - ?

Comment: Is that a TeXnical question or a question about Hebrew? In the latter case this question might be off-topic here and you may have a better chance of asking it elsewhere (A handful regular users of TeX.SX are active in related fields, but the majority probably does not know about hyphenation rules in Biblical Hebrew ...).

Answer (score 3):

It is permissible to break words at a maqaf. My copy of the BHS does, anyway.

This does not happen automatically with `xetex`, but you can achieve this by specifying a hyphenation character with `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{SBL BibLit}[Script=Hebrew,Contextuals=Alternate]
\newfontfamily\hebhyphen{SBL BibLit}[Script=Hebrew,Contextuals=Alternate,HyphenChar=־]
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5.5cm}
וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֗ים יִקָּו֨וּ הַמַּ֜יִם מִתַּ֤חַת הַשָּׁמַ֨יִם֙ אֶל־מָקֹ֣ום אֶחָ֔ד וְתֵרָאֶ֖ה הַיַּבָּשָׁ֑ה וַֽיְהִי־כֵֽן׃

\hebhyphen
וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֗ים יִקָּו֨וּ הַמַּ֜יִם מִתַּ֤חַת הַשָּׁמַ֨יִם֙ אֶל־מָקֹ֣ום אֶחָ֔ד וְתֵרָאֶ֖ה הַיַּבָּשָׁ֑ה וַֽיְהִי־כֵֽן׃
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For completeness, here's how you could do it in `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[he,main]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Contextuals=Alternate]{SBL BibLit}
\exhyphenchar=`\־
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5.5cm}
וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֗ים יִקָּו֨וּ הַמַּ֜יִם מִתַּ֤חַת הַשָּׁמַ֨יִם֙ אֶל־מָקֹ֣ום אֶחָ֔ד וְתֵרָאֶ֖ה הַיַּבָּשָׁ֑ה וַֽיְהִי־כֵֽן׃
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In luatex you can set `\exhyphenchar``\־` (only a single `; I don't know how to enter it).

Comment: Thanks @JavierBezos, that is better! I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JavierBezos, I notice there is an `exhyphenchar` line in the `babel` ini files. Is this something that could go in `babel-he.ini`?

Comment: Yes, this field will be filled in a future release, but `babel` has to do something with it before.