# Hyphenation character makes Hebrew words disappear in HarfTeX

Tags: luatex, hebrew, harftex, luahbtex

Hebrew uses [maqaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_punctuation#Hyphen_and_maqaf) as a hyphenation character, and I have to [declare](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447275/135685) it if I want to use it instead of the usual hyphen. However, this declaration somehow makes certain words disappear in Hebrew when I use [HarfTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493180/135685) with LuaLaTeX. Please see my example below:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel} 
\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[RawFeature={mode=harf},Script=Hebrew,Language=Default]{SBL Hebrew}
\exhyphenchar=`\־ % If I comments this out, the words are displayed correctly.

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}

כׇּל־הַשֹּׁמֵ֖עַ

כִּֽי־שָׁמַ֧ע

כִּֽי־בָרֵ֣ךְ

\end{document}
```

[image: Missing words]

**KLUDGE:** If I put the maqaf in slanted (doesn't have visible effect), it seems to circumvent the problem, but I assume there is a bug somewhere.

Comment: What is the problem if you don't change \exhyphenchar?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I need maqaf as a hyphen in my document, because otherwise I would get an ugly layout (and even more underfull hboxes).

Comment: Marcel just pushed a fix to the luaotfload github. So with the next version it will work. Btw: the name of the binary is now luahbtex (and it is used by default by lualatex in a current tex system). And with a current fontspec you can use `Renderer=Harfbuzz` instead of the Rawfeature.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much indeed your quick help, I really appreciate!